# Java, Swing, Netbeans: how to create an interface similar to the iPhone's SMS screen?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm looking to create an interface similar to that of the iPhone's SMS screen. More specifically I'm looking to replicate the "bubbles" coming from each side of the page which contain the messages, as shown here http://www.bidslammer.com/images/iphone_shot1.png .

I do also want to recreate the date and time above the bubbles like you can see in that image. I need to be able to do this by code because its use will be to display the messages that it receives over my socket connection, and show the messages I send over the socket.

I'm really new to Java, and even newer to Swing, so I'm looking for some pointers on how I should go about this.

Can anyone offer my any suggestions about how I would go about doing this? I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, just a few pointers, perhaps some things I should learn how to use/do and perhaps a helpful tutorial or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for "swing tutorial" gives a lot of tutorial links, so just pick one. When I was learning Swing I used original [Java Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html).

As for some pointers, I think good idea is to use images to represent the bubbles - that will be the easiest. Inherit some basic component like JLabel or JPanel and override a drawing method - do a custom drawing. First draw the bubble image and then the text over it. [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) may help with image drawing.

Generally with custom component drawing you use [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class, which provides a lot of useful drawing methods.

Answer (score 0):

The [sticky notes demo](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/sticky_note) might get you started in the right direction.

Even though that demo is a NetBeans platform module, the sticky note itself is a pure Swing component and should be usable without the platform.